# Apache2 sql injection rule not starting

Tags: linux, apache2, mod-security

[image: apache 2 not starting]

The config for modsecurity is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The file /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_41_sql_injection_attacks.data is missing or not readable by the web server daemon. Just like the error message says.

Comment: Yes , but How to find it , or better say, how to make it work ? because when I installed everything , it was no folder active rules and I created it.

Comment: You should read the documentation before trying blindly something you found in some random blog. Check this two links https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project

Answer (score 0):

Check if "modsecurity_41_sql_injection_attacks.data" is in "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules" and copy it to "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules".